# About the SSE compare instructions not found in mmintrin.h or emmintrin.h?

Tags: gcc, comparison, header-files, sse, intrinsics

I found that the instructions for greater than, less than and equal to are called with these functions.

```
emmintrin

_mm_cmpeq_epi8 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
_mm_cmplt_epi8 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
_mm_cmpgt_epi8 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)

mmintrin
_mm_cmpeq_pi8 (__m64 __m1, __m64 __m2)
_m_pcmpeqb (__m64 __m1, __m64 __m2)
_mm_cmpgt_pi8 (__m64 __m1, __m64 __m2)
_m_pcmpgtb (__m64 __m1, __m64 __m2)
```

But what about these ones? Are they in the SSE intrinsic headers somewhere or do I use inline assembler for those ones. I use GCC as my compiler so if someone has the following instructions as examples that would be nice.

[pcmpxxb - Compares 16 8bit integers.](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse2.php)

Compare Codes (the xx parts above):

```
le - Less than or equal to.

ne - Not equal.

nlt - Not less than.

nle - Not less than or equal to.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers there are only two basic comparison *instructions*, `PCMPGTx` and `PCMPEQx`. The other comparison *intrinsics* are derived form these, e.g. `_mm_cmplt_epi8(v0, v1)` is just `_mm_cmpgt_epi8(v1, v0)` - it's the same underlying instruction (`PCMPGTB`) with the operands switched. It's possible to build all the other comparison intrinsics from these instructions, and while most headers provide `lt` as well as `gt` as a convenience, any other conditions are generally left for the programmer to take care of when coding.

Comment: But what about `less than or equal to`? Is that meant to be coded in inline assembly then?

Comment: `le` is just the logical negation of `gt` - so you just do e.g. `_mm_cmgpt_epi8` and then invert the result (if needed), e.g. using `_mm_xor_si128`.

Comment: But isn't that two operations instead of just one?

Comment: It's two *instructions*, but only if your program logic requires it - you can often eliminate the need to invert the comparison mask by careful coding.